# Blender weird behaviour when scaling

Tags: transforms

I am pretty new to blender and it looks like i have "killed" some default settings. I have no idea how to fix this.
i just marked an object, press s to scale...and just some axis are scaling but not the sphere!? what happened? what did i do!?

movie here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cet24v9jfekajud/sphere_not_scaling.mov?dl=0

Comment: on the top righ of your 3D view > Options, you've enable the Transform > Affect Only > Origins option, it allows you to move the object's origin

Comment: thank you! you saved my day!!!